# How to speed up geopandas.sjoin_nearest using spatial indexing?

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-index

I have 2 data frames with routes and linestrings:

```
df1 = {
  "Route": ["AL013-AL015", "AL013-AL014", "AL013-AL011"],
  "Linestring": ["LINESTRING (20.40350 42.06510, 19.70210 42.16300)", "LINESTRING (20.40350 42.06510, 19.84780 41.78380)", "LINESTRING (20.40350 42.06510, 20.25610 41.60390)"],
}

df2 = {
  "Route": ["NO0A3-NO071", "NO0A3-NO091", "NO0A3-NO0A3"],
  "Linestring": ["LINESTRING (8.53910 62.52120, 14.78250 66.69440)", "LINESTRING (8.53910 62.52120, 8.70540 59.49660)", "LINESTRING (8.53910 62.52120, 8.53910 62.52120)"],
}
```

The problem is that they are large (df1 has approx 2 million rows and df2 has 300k rows). I want to use `geopandas.sjoin_nearest` like this:

```
df_new = gpd.sjoin_nearest(df2, df1, how = 'left')
```

Nevertheless, the computational time is very long. Are there any ways to speed it up? I was googling it and found spatial indexing in geopandas. But I am not sure if it works with linestrings. Could someone explain to me how to apply spatial indexing to linestrings or any other ways to speed up the join?

Comment: Setting `max_distance` parameter in sjoin_nearest will make it alot faster. If you can estimate the max distance. That way it wont have to calculate ~60 billion distances

Comment: FYI, the `sjoin_nearest()` function of GeoPandas already uses a spatial index under the hood (and so is already a lot faster compared to naively calculating distances for all combinations, but for such a large dataset that will still take time). But as @BERA mentioned, and if applicable for your use case, specifying a `max_distance` search radius can further improve the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speed it up by setting a max distance:

> Maximum distance within which to query for nearest geometry. Must be
> greater than 0. The max_distance used to search for nearest items in
> the tree may have a significant impact on performance by reducing the
> number of input geometries that are evaluated for nearest items in the
> tree.

You will have to find the minimum distance. For example like below.

I had to set a distance of 100 km to join a powerline (7000 features) to each river (370000 features). It sped it up from 27 s to 20 s which isnt great but I suspect it is because of my test data covering all of Sweden in an uneaven distribution.

```
import os, timeit
import geopandas as gpd

infolder = r"/home/bera/Drives/data1/data/Topografi_100/909a2511-615d-477b-aad3-8693e1425c3c"

powerline = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(infolder, "ledningar_sverige.gpkg"), layer="ledningslinje")
powerline["powerlineid"] = range(powerline.shape[0]) #Create a unique id field
print(powerline.shape[0])
#6848
river = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(infolder, "hydrografi_sverige.gpkg"), layer="hydrolinje")
river["riverid"] = range(river.shape[0])
print(river.shape[0])
#371092

#Sjoin nearest with no max distance
start = timeit.default_timer()
sjoin1 = gpd.sjoin_nearest(left_df=river, right_df=powerline, how="left")
print(f"Computation time: {round(timeit.default_timer()-start, 2)} s")
#Computation time: 26.85 s

#Did all rivers get a nearest powerline?
#sjoin1["powerlineid"].isnull().value_counts()
#False    374426 #Yes, there are no nulls

#Sjoin with near distance 100 m
del(sjoin1)
start = timeit.default_timer()
sjoin2 = gpd.sjoin_nearest(left_df=river, right_df=powerline, how="left", max_distance=100)
print(f"Computation time: {round(timeit.default_timer()-start, 2)} s")
#Computation time: 7.74 s
#sjoin2["powerlineid"].isnull().value_counts()
#True     342673 #For 340k rivers there isnt a powerline within 100 m
#False     30375 

#Is 1000 m enough?
del(sjoin2)
start = timeit.default_timer()
sjoin3 = gpd.sjoin_nearest(left_df=river, right_df=powerline, how="left", max_distance=1000)
print(f"Computation time: {round(timeit.default_timer()-start, 2)} s")
#Computation time: 8.95 s
#sjoin3["powerlineid"].isnull().value_counts()
#True     290566 #No
#False     82580

#100000
start = timeit.default_timer()
sjoin3 = gpd.sjoin_nearest(left_df=river, right_df=powerline, how="left", max_distance=1000000)
print(f"Computation time: {round(timeit.default_timer()-start, 2)} s")
sjoin3["powerlineid"].isnull().value_counts()
#Computation time: 19.52 s
#False    374426 #Now all rivers got a joined powerline
```

[image]